# Red5 RTMPT streaming over port 80 exception

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, red5, flash-media-server

I followed [Mondain's post](http://gregoire.org/2009/01/28/rtmpt-and-red5/) to set up Red5 with RTMPT over port 80 and it mostly works.

However, on a Mac the stream breaks down after a couple of seconds. Here is the relevant excerpt from the Red5 console:

```
[WARN] [NioProcessor-16] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Exception caught null 
[WARN] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-4] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Closing RTMPTConnection from 98.207.104.42 : 37953 to 54.245.114.146 (in: 64790 out 3665 ), with id 25769, due to too much inactivity (79868 ms), last ping sent 4999 ms ago 
[WARN] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-4] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - This often happens if YOUR Red5 application generated an exception on start-up. Check earlier in the log for that exception first!
```

Did anyone manage to get RTMPT streaming working on a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

I debug and develop on Mac with Red5. I have had no issues with Red5 on OSX.
The log message actually tells you that there might be some other exception elsewhere.
Also you did not tell anything about your Red5 version. You should try to use the latest snapshot/release.
"due to too much inactivity" can also happen if you simply forget to close your old browser instance connected to a red5 server while you restart red5.